# Proving convexity of $h(y) = \inf_{Ax=y}{f(x)}$ for convex $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Came across this question in an optimization course:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be convex, and let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times{n}}$. Consider:

$$h(y) = \inf_{Ax=y}{\{f(x)}\}$$

Prove that $h$ is convex.

Any help? It's not the traditional preservation of convexity under infimum.
I believe the direction should be something like: Assume $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the $x$ for which $h(y_0)=f(x_0)$. Thus,

$$h(y_0)=f(x_0)\leq{f(x_0+z)}$$

for any $z$ that holds $Az=0$.

From here, I'm not sure how to continue...

Comment: I am not sure why you did not appreciate my answer, but your statement "It's not the traditional preservation of convexity under infimum" is not true and my answer showed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and assume that
$$
u = \alpha v + (1-\alpha)w,\quad \alpha\in(0,1), \;u,v,w\in\mathbb{R}^m.
$$ Assume $A^{-1}(v)=\{x|Ax = v\}$ is not empty. By the assumption, we can find $x$ such that $Ax = v$ and 
$$
h(v) \leq f(x)\leq h(v)+\epsilon. 
$$ Also assume that $A^{-1}(w)$ is not empty and find $x'$ such that
$$
h(w)\leq f(x')\leq h(w)+\epsilon.
$$ Now, note that $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)x' \in A^{-1}(u)$. Therefore, it holds that
$$
h(u) \leq f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)x') \leq \alpha f(x) +(1-\alpha)f(x')\leq \alpha h(v)+(1-\alpha)h(w) +\epsilon.
$$ Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we get
$$h(u) \leq \alpha h(v)+(1-\alpha)h(w) ,
$$as desired.

If $A^{-1}(v)$ is empty, according to the definition, we have
$$
h(v) = \inf_{x\in A^{-1}(v)} f(x) = \inf \varnothing = \infty.
$$ Hence if one of the sets $A^{-1}(v)$ or $A^{-1}(w)$ is empty, then
$$
h(u) \leq \alpha h(v)+(1-\alpha)h(w)=\infty
$$ is obvious. (But it is desirable to assume that $A :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is surjective.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x,y) = f(x) + \delta( (x,y) | Ax=y)$, where $\delta$ is the support function that takes the value 0 if $Ax=y$, and $\infty$ otherwise. Since $g$ is jointly convex and $h$ is the infinimum over one coordinate (*partial minimization*), $h$ is convex.